# Selenium Grid 2 using RemoteWebDriver throwing spurious exception

Tags: selenium, playframework, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I've got a Play! Framework application (based on v1.2.3) using the WebDrive module (based on v0.2) to run the Selenium tests in a browser through WebDriver.  I've customised this module to allow me to fire up a RemoteWebDriver to run the tests on another machine.

If I connect this RemoteWebDriver directly to a standalone Selenium server (using v2.14) then everything works fine.

If I set up a Grid configuration with a hub server and a node server that registers with the hub, and then point the RemoteWebDriver at the hub, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Could not start Selenium session: org%2Eopenqa%2Egrid%2Ecommon%2Eexception%2EGridException%3A+Error+forwarding+the+new+session+cannot+find+%3A+%7BbrowserName%3D%2Achrome%7D; duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.14.0', revision: 'unknown', time: '2011-11-29 13:13:16'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-34-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:147)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:400)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:76)
at play.modules.webdrive.WebDriverRunner.runRemote(WebDriverRunner.java:204)
at play.modules.webdrive.WebDriverRunner.runDecider(WebDriverRunner.java:64)
at play.modules.webdrive.WebDriverRunner.main(WebDriverRunner.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: org%2Eopenqa%2Egrid%2Ecommon%2Eexception%2EGridException%3A+Error+forwarding+the+new+session+cannot+find+%3A+%7BbrowserName%3D%2Achrome%7D
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:123)
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.selenesedriver.NewSession.apply(NewSession.java:34)
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.selenesedriver.NewSession.apply(NewSession.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.SeleneseCommandExecutor.execute(SeleneseCommandExecutor.java:132)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:382)
... 5 more
```

I am specifying in my capabilities that I want a "firefox" driver, not a "* chrome" one.  I've seen that "**browser name*" is the older style Selenium RC definition, but I'm not using that anywhere, only the RemoteWebDriver style definition.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
//      capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>" + capabilities.getBrowserName());
        CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(new URL(System.getProperty("webdrive.remoteUrl")), new URL(appUrlBase + "/@tests/init"), capabilities);
        WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, capabilities);

        System.out.println("~ Starting tests remotely with " + capabilities.getBrowserName());   

        runTests(seleniumTests, webDriver);
```

and it falls over on the line where I create the new RemoteWebDriver.  I've tried both methods of setting the browser and the sysout confirms that it is in there correctly.  I never get to see the second sysout.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Is firefox installed on the client node?

Comment: Try removing the setBrowserName.